# ArgumentException was unhandled - Empty path name is not legal

Tags: vb.net, argumentexception

I'm a beginner, trying to similarly replicate Microsoft's Notepad, but I'm getting this message. At the moment I'm trying to code the 'New' Item in the ToolStripMenu. Brief summary: So far if the user presses 'New', they are prompted with "Do you wanted to save the changes made to this document?", they can choose No, which clears the information in the document, or Cancel, which returns them back to where they were, as planned. However, pressing 'Yes' gives me the error "ArgumentException was unhandled - Empty path name is not legal'

```
Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim intResult As Integer = Nothing
    Dim dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog

    dlg.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt"
    intResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes made to this document?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)

    If intResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        RichTextBox1.SaveFile(dlg.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
    ElseIf intResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
    Else
        Return
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`FileName` is empty. SaveFileDialog was declared, but never used.  Your code doesn't make a lot of sense so you can either show the dialog...

```
Dim dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
dlg.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt"
dlg.Title = "Choose Text File"
dlg.ShowDialog()

intResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes made to this document?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
```

[SaveFile Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

or can check if they have specified a `FileName` and then run your logic.

```
If dlg.FileName <> "" then
'   do save logic '
End If
```

Comment: Everything works as it should, but now pressing 'new' prompts the SaveFileDialog.

Comment: How are u currently using the dlg?